Querying Map of Maps in Flutter and Firebase
I have this model for a map of maps in Firebase.
class Names {
  UserInformationModelMap names;
  Names({
    required this.names,
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return <String, dynamic>{
      'names': names.toMap(),
    };
  }

  factory Names.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return Names(
      names: UserInformationModelMap.fromMap(
        map['names'] as Map<String, dynamic>,
      ),
    );
  }

  factory Names.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> doc) {
    return Names(
      names: UserInformationModelMap.fromSnapshot(
        doc,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class UserInformationModelMap {
  WholeNameMap fullName;
  String? uid;
  UserInformationModelMap({
    required this.fullName,
    this.uid,
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return <String, dynamic>{
      uid!: fullName.toMap(),
    };
  }

  factory UserInformationModelMap.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return UserInformationModelMap(
      fullName: WholeNameMap.fromMap(map['fullName'] as Map<String, dynamic>),
    );
  }

  factory UserInformationModelMap.fromSnapshot(
      DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> doc) {
    return UserInformationModelMap(
      fullName: WholeNameMap.fromMap(doc['fullName'] as Map<String, dynamic>),
    );
  }
}

class WholeNameMap {
  String firstName;
  String lastName;

  WholeNameMap({
    required this.firstName,
    required this.lastName,
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return <String, dynamic>{
      'firstName': firstName,
      'lastName': lastName,
    };
  }

  factory WholeNameMap.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return WholeNameMap(
      firstName: map['firstName'] as String,
      lastName: map['lastName'] as String,
    );
  }
}

This enables me to upload information into Firebase which is a map of maps. You can refer to the image to see how it looks like.

Now, what I wanted to achieve is to query the data from the Firebase and show in on my application using a ListViewBuilder.
Can anyone help me fix my model? Specifically fromSnapshot since that is where the querying happens.
Here's what I get when querying.


As the error says: you have no fullName key anywhere in your data, so this code won't work:
WholeNameMap.fromMap(doc['fullName']

It looks like your WholeNameMap represents on of the entries in your names map, and I'm assuming that your Names class is meant to represent the entire names data.
In that case your Names.fromSnapshot needs to parse all the multiple 1af... keys in names. So something like:
factory Names.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> doc) {
  // doc is actually of type Map<String, Map<String, String>>
  doc.forEach((key, value) {
    final names = value as Map<String,String>;
    print("Key: ${key}, First name: ${names['firstName']}, Last name: ${names['lastName'}");
  }
  ...

